# How can I read a Java long as unsigned and store its value in a BigInteger?

Tags: java, types

I have to handle an 8-byte unsigned integer type in Java somehow.

My 8-byte unsigned integer is stored in a byte array wrapped by ByteBuffer. It comes from a data logger database and contains very big numbers.

This is how I deal with 4-byte integers to read them them as unsigned:

```
((long) (bytebuffer.getInt() & 0xFFFFFFFFL));
```

Unfortunately this:

```
((BigInteger) (bytebuffer.getLong() & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFL));
```

doesn't work.

How can I store the number **2^64-1** and read it as **2^64-1**?

Comment: Not an answer to the question per se, but [`BigInteger(int signum, byte[] magnitude, int off, int len)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-int-byte:A-int-int-) could be useful to you since you're starting out with a `byte` array.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Java's signed `long`s, the most significant bit is worth -(2<sup>63</sup>).  If it were unsigned, then that bit would be worth positive 2<sup>63</sup>.  The difference is 2<sup>64</sup>.

First, create a `BigInteger` using the `long` value.  Then, if it's negative, apply the unsigned correction by adding 2<sup>64</sup>, or `1 << 64`, to the `BigInteger`.

```
BigInteger result = BigInteger.valueOf(bytebuffer.getLong());
if (result.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) < 0) {
    result = result.add(BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(64));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can convert it to an unsigned string and then parse it to `BigInteger`:

```
new BigInteger(Long.toUnsignedString(bytebuffer.getLong()))
```

Probably not the most efficient solution, but possibly the simplest.

Or you can borrow this implementation out of the `Long` class:

```
static BigInteger toUnsignedBigInteger(long i) {
    if (i >= 0L)
        return BigInteger.valueOf(i);
    else {
        int upper = (int) (i >>> 32);
        int lower = (int) i;

        // return (upper << 32) + lower
        return (BigInteger.valueOf(Integer.toUnsignedLong(upper))).shiftLeft(32).
            add(BigInteger.valueOf(Integer.toUnsignedLong(lower)));
    }
}
```